# How to annotate PDF files inside Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, pdf, annotations

Is is possible to annotate PDF files inside Google Drive?

In the Google Drive PDF Viewer I could not find any annotating options. However, is there an extension that allows annotating PDF files?

By annotating, I essentially mean text-selection marking but also notes and comments would be nice.

Comment: For those who ended up here as a result of a google search, selected a region of text in the pdf (uploaded to google drive) you wish to comment results in a comment button appearing, which you can then use to add comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DocHub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dochub-edit-and-sign-pdf/adgncicbhbjfpijkdmbijninnhnmiblj?hl=en-US) allows you to highlight text and add comments.

Comment: It works but I didn't find it as intuitive/pretty as the Google Docs comment function. For DocHub I found myself highlighting some text and then putting a comment hovering next to it. Gets the job done.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not present in Android, as opposed to google docs. You can't annotate in Windows and see then in your android phone.

Comment: It is unclear to me, how this answers the question (as per Stack Exchange convention, that answers should answer the question posted). It should perhaps be a comment instead? Or explain in more detail, just how can having PDF Annotation in Google Drive be achieved using DocHub.

Comment: For DocHub, I noticed that when I added a comment and saved it as a pdf later, the comment didn't transfer. All that transferred was the little comment icon but it did not let me click on it. I do not know if this is an error on my end and if I should not save it as a pdf or what.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you upload a PDF to Google drive and convert it to a Google doc (or right click and open with Google Docs instead of Google Drive Viewer) you can add comments in collaboration with others (in the same way as with a Google doc) by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or selecting text and right clicking. The drawback is you may lose some formatting when opening some documents in Google Docs.

Comment: Are the annotations persistent if you convert it back to PDF?

Comment: No the annotations live with the google doc. If you want to make annotations that travel with a specific pdf file see here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/feature-details/acrobatpro/pdfs/adding-comments-to-a-pdf-document.pdf

Comment: A problem is many pdf can't be converted, in my case pdf with Latex math equations convert to garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Chrome Notable PDF Add-On](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notable-pdf-%E2%80%93-viewer-and/ecnphlgnajanjnkcmbpancdjoidceilk).

To quote a couple of extracts from that site:

> you will also have the ability to post annotations and collaborate with others. … You can then post annotations along your files and have the ability to invite collaborators to post annotations on your file.

Comment: Thanks! But since it is a Chrome extension, can it be also used with Firefox? Furthermore, all data is not stored in the PDF but at the extension's servers, correct? Thus, if I download the PDF, all notes are gone.

Comment: This is a payed app, it's only free for 1 week

Answer (score -2):

Adobe Acrobat Viewer app will allow you to annotate and save documents into cloud.